# Render Divi Tags via WordPress API

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api, divi, divi-theme

I am trying to pull out a page via the WordPress API like so:

```
/wp-json/wp/v2/pages/MY_PAGE_ID?status=publish
```

However the page was built using the Divi Page Builder module and includes the various Divi tags in the content such as:

```
[et_pb_section fb_built=”1″ _builder_version=”4.6.0″ _module_preset=”default” module_alignment=”center” min_height=”627px” custom_padding=”||1px|||”]
```

I was wondering if there was a way of ensuring that the WordPress API can compile/render the full HTML generated by these tags before it's sent back via JSON to my front-end application?

Thanks very much for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like shortcodes.
You could try to work with `apply_filters()`
Source: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/rest_post_dispatch/

To filter the shortcodes to actual HTML use the `do_shortcode()` function.
Source: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/

Comment: Exactly - you would do this in PHP on the Wordpress instance. It may interfer with other stuff that depends on the API, keep that in mind, and test it. (for example the gutenberg editor)

Comment: Thanks very much for this, I'll give it a look - I guess the do_shortcodes can be done on the rest API init. Appreciate your time on this, I'll give it a try now - if it works I'll come back and accept this answer

Comment: Might be tricky - but I'm sure there is a viable solution =)

Comment: Worked perfectly!
I cobbled something together from your reply and this: https://medium.com/how-to-react/visual-composer-wordpress-rest-api-reactjs-to-create-a-awesome-site-790db78e1e0d Thanks again!